# CSS Overflow hassel

Tags: css, overflow

So, I have a popup information "window" on my site.  Basically, I've created a light-box type widow for online help and other informative things.  It's been working great.  My closing button is a little bubble that sticks outside the top-left corner and blends perfectly with the ridged border of the popup window.

Then I discovered a problem.  If there was too much info, it would just print outside of the box.  No big deal, I just added overflow:auto to the css.  No more printing outside the box.  However,  my little "bubble" for closing the window also gets clipped.

I don't want to put this window closing icon inside the window- I really think my design is unique and cool.  Does anyone know of a way to use overflow on an element, but still keep at least one element going outside?

Thanks, Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolute positioning: http://jsfiddle.net/EkPmD/1/

Comment: That was easier than I thought.  I spent too much time focusing on the closer, that I didn't think about a container.

Answer (score 0):

Put your text in a container and set overflow on that.